# How to get an object or value from _NSCoreDataTaggedObjectID

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7

I was following the example by apple: (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/fetchExpressions.html) to fetch distinct "values"

```
NSEntityDescription *ahrsMessage = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AHRSMessage" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *distinctFetch = [NSFetchRequest new];
    [distinctFetch setEntity:ahrsMessage];
    [distinctFetch setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
    [distinctFetch setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
    [distinctFetch setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"flightRecordings"]];

    NSError *e = nil;
    id requestedValue = nil;
    NSArray *objects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:distinctFetch error:&e];
    if (objects == nil) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR");
    }


    for (NSDictionary *dict in objects) {
        NSLog(@"dict: %@", dict);

       [dict objectForKey:@"flightRecordings"];

    }
```

When I explore the value `objects[1]` in the debugger i see my key is `_PFEncodedString *` and my value is `_NSCoreDataTaggedObjectID *`  What I'm unclear about is how to actually get my CoreData object back out of this datatype.

Answer (score 6):

I just came across this post looking for an answer about this myself. So in case someone runs into this issue, you can get the actual **NSManagedObject** by passing the value from the result's dictionary in NSManagedObjectContext's **objectWithID:** method.

So something along the lines of:

```
NSManagedObjectID *managedObjectID = [dict objectForKey:@"fetched_property_name"]
NSManagedObject *managedObject = [moc objectWithID:managedObjectID]
```